# For $f(x) = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$ prove that $f^{-1}(y) = \frac{d}{dy}f^{-1}(y)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

I am looking for verification on proving that for $$
f(x) = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}
$$
the derivative of the inverse function ***is*** the inverse function itself: $$
f^{-1}(y) = \frac{d}{dy}f^{-1}(y).
$$

Obviously the statement is true because

- $f(x) = \log(x)$ and therefore $f^{-1}(y) = \exp(y)$
- And because $\exp(y) = \frac{d}{dy}\exp(y)$.

However, I want to prove the fact using only the definitions of $f$ and $f^{-1}$.

So far I know that by the fundamental theorem of calculus $$
f'(x) = 1/x.
$$

And by the inverse function theorem I also know that $$
\frac{d}{dy} f^{-1}(y) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}~ \text{ such that } f(x)=y.
$$

And therefore $$
\frac{d}{dy} f^{-1}(y) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(y))} = f^{-1}(y).
$$

So I guess that solves it... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is mostly fine. To make it airtight, you should mention that the derivative of $f$ is strictly positive on $(0,\infty)$ so the inverse function theorem actually applies.

Comment: Yes, I did that elsewhere. Thanks!